# Assign value to a cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to put the value of the cell that is after the one with the string "Senast", into cell Q2. The code below does not work. Any ideas why?

```
Sub Find_Data()

    Dim item_in_review As Variant
    Dim row_number As Long

    For row_number = 1 To 1000 Step 1
        item_in_review = Sheets("Investor_Importerad data").Range("A" & row_number)
        If InStr(item_in_review, "Senast") Then
            row_number = row_number + 1
            Worksheets("Översikt innehavCells").Cells(2, "Q").Value = Worksheets("Investor_Importerad data").Cells(row_number, "A").Value
            Exit For
        End If

        If item_in_review = 300 Then
            MsgBox "300"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next row_number

End Sub
```

Comment: *'Does not work'* is neither a valid error code nor a valid error description. What is it doing or not doing that is contrary to what you are expecting?

Comment: Get "Subscipt out of range"

Comment: *<sigh>* ... and pray tell, which code line does the error occur on?

Comment: The row that is getting marked:

Worksheets("Översikt innehavCells").Cells(2, "Q").Value = Worksheets("Investor_Importerad data").Cells(row_number, "A").Value

Comment: Go to `Worksheets("Översikt innehavCells")` then go to the VBe's Immediate window and paste in `?activesheet.name` and hit enter. Copy that result and paste it as the worksheet name into `Worksheets("Översikt innehavCells")`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking to either a wildcard match to *Senast* or the number 300 as a true number. Whichever comes first, you exit your For ... Next loop.

The following is filled with numerous error trapping and criteria conditions that should isolate your problem.

```
Sub Find_Data()

    Dim rSenast As Variant, r300 As Variant, wsn As String

    wsn = "Översikt innehavCells"
    Dim row_number As Long

    With Worksheets("Investor_Importerad data")
        rSenast = Application.Match("*senast*", .Range("a:a"), 0)
        r300 = Application.Match(300, .Range("a:a"), 0)
        If IsError(r300) Then _
            r300 = Application.Match(Format(300, "0"), .Range("a:a"), 0)

        Select Case True
            Case CBool(IsNumeric(rSenast) And IsNumeric(r300))
                If r300 < rSenast Then
                    If MsgBox("300 found before 'senast" & vbLf & "Continue with value transfer?", vbYesNo, "Continue?") <> vbYes Then _
                        Exit Sub
                End If
            Case CBool(IsError(rSenast) And IsError(r300))
                MsgBox "Neither 'senast' nor 300 can be found"
                Exit Sub
            Case CBool(IsError(rSenast) And IsNumeric(r300))
                MsgBox "300 can be found at row " & r300
                Exit Sub
        End Select

        On Error GoTo No_Such_Worksheet
        If .Cells(rSenast + 1, "A").Value <> vbNullString Then
            Worksheets(wsn).Cells(2, "Q") = .Cells(rSenast + 1, "A").Value
        Else
            MsgBox .Cells(rSenast + 1, "A").Address(0, 0) & " appears to be empty"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End With

    Exit Sub

No_Such_Worksheet:
    With Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets("Investor_Importerad data"))
        .Name = wsn
    End With
    Resume

End Sub
```

Comment: IThat code just destroyed the functionality of my workbook. And for some reason I was not able to open it correctly... Then I had to delete a bunch of worksheets to make the workbook work correctly again. So, no that code did not work...

Comment: That code was tested in a workbook that contained a Översikt innehavCells worksheet and in one that didn't. If it *' just destroyed the functionality of my workbook'* then you have problems that are too severe for my meager skills. Good luck with your project and please remember not to post duplicates of your previous questions.

Comment: On the positive side I solved it now. Thanks for the inputs anyhow.